# Action of base space on homology of homotopy fiber, when the fiber is an Eilenberg Maclane space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, fibration

I am trying to understand a proof I found in a paper by Wagoner about delooping of algebraic K-theory (proposition 1.2 for those interested). For this I have a fibration $BE\to BG\to BG^{ab}$, with $E=[G,G]$, and I want to understand the action of $BG^{ab}$ on $H_*(BE)$. The paper seems to assume that this action is given by conjugation, in which case by a lemma from the paper (1.3) and some standard group homology, the action is trivial in the case of interest.

What I don't understand, is why the action of $G^{ab}$ on $H_*(E)$ coming from the homotopy fibration would be the conjugation action coming from group homology.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you know the statement that $H_*(BG, \mathbb Z)=H_*^{grp}(G, \mathbb Z)$?. Also what is your definition of group homology? Via explicit formulas or derived functors (ideally both.)

Comment: also for a general fibration $F \to E \to B$, do you know how $\pi_1(B)$ acts on the fiber? (As a generalization of the action for covering spaces, i.e. $F$ discrete.)

Comment: Sorry I'd like to answer, but the level of detail will vary depending on whats useful for you

Comment: Dear @AndresMejia I do indeed know both of those things, though my study of group homology didn't give me the chance to practice translating from $H_*(BG)$ to $H_*(G)$ (Weibel's homological algebra chapter 6) and nor have I encountered the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $F$ outside of the exercise from Hatcher's algebraic topology defining it (4.3.19).